# Fatal Python error: could not acquire lock for <_io.BufferedReader name='<stdin>'> at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads

Tags: python

I want to write a python script in which if I doesn't enter any value through input command, then it should assign a default a value to my variable after 30 seconds, my platform is windows 7

```
from func_timeout import func_timeout, FunctionTimedOut

def doit():

    value = input("enter")

try:
    doitReturnValue = func_timeout(5, doit)

except FunctionTimedOut:
    value = "default value"
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
"C:\Users\Arpit\PycharmProjects\Complete Test\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Arpit/PycharmProjects/Complete Test/test_for_timeout.py"
enterFatal Python error: could not acquire lock for <_io.BufferedReader name='<stdin>'> at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads
Python runtime state: finalizing (tstate=00000000003CAE20)

Thread 0x00000c18 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Arpit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 1027 in _wait_for_tstate_lock
  File "C:\Users\Arpit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 1015 in join
  File "C:\Users\Arpit\PycharmProjects\Complete Test\venv\lib\site-packages\func_timeout\StoppableThread.py", line 126 in run
  File "C:\Users\Arpit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Arpit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x0000106c (most recent call first):
  File "C:/Users/Arpit/PycharmProjects/Complete Test/test_for_timeout.py", line 7 in doit
  File "C:\Users\Arpit\PycharmProjects\Complete Test\venv\lib\site-packages\func_timeout\dafunc.py", line 68 in funcwrap
  File "C:\Users\Arpit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "C:\Users\Arpit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Arpit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00001850 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>

Process finished with exit code 3
```

Comment: Is this resolving you issue:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Arpit/PycharmProjects/Complete Test/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    i, o, e = select.select( [sys.stdin],[],[], 30 )
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any limitation you are try the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) package.

There is an asynchronous package [`aioconsole`](https://pypi.org/project/aioconsole/), it\' allow to wait for a user input while performing other tasks asynchronously.

In order to install this package please run: `pip install aioconsole`

The following code will wait 30 seconds for the user input. If the user didn't input anything at this time it will continue (`raise asyncio.TimeoutError`) and set the value to the default one.

```
import asyncio
import aioconsole

async def main(main_loop):
    t = main_loop.create_task(aioconsole.ainput())
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(t, timeout=30)
        value = t.result()
    except asyncio.TimeoutError as _:
        value = "default value"
    print(value)
    return value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    value = l.run_until_complete(main(l))
    l.close()
```

---

Regarding your code, I have tried it and it worked for me with some minor changes:

```
from func_timeout import func_timeout, FunctionTimedOut
def doit():
    value = input("enter")
    return value  # Need to return the value.
try:
    value = func_timeout(5, doit)  # Set the return value to the same variable name
except FunctionTimedOut as _:
    value = "default value"
print(value)
```

Comment: Thanks, the first code worked for me but the second one is showing this error:

Fatal Python error: could not acquire lock for <_io.BufferedReader name='<stdin>'> at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads
Python runtime state: finalizing (tstate=000000000045AF50)

Comment: By the way my platform is windows 7

Comment: I would suggest to use the first method (code) due to the fact that it uses built in `python3` functions/abilities.
Regarding the seconds code, try reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267439/fatal-python-error-and-bufferedwriter it might help you.

Comment: can you please tell me how to call the "value" variable outside this function: "async def main(main_loop):"

Comment: I edited the code with how to return the `value` argument back from the `main` function.